# How to integrate spring actuator in a non spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

i have a GWT application which is not a spring boot application and i managed to integrate actuator v1.5.9 with spring v4.3.3 with this configuration class.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricExportAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsChannelAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsDropwizardAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@Import({ EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class, ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class,
  EndpointAutoConfiguration.class, HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class, MetricExportAutoConfiguration.class,
  MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricsChannelAutoConfiguration.class,
  MetricsDropwizardAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class,
  PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,EndpointProperties.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@PropertySource("classpath:Application.properties")
public class HealthCheckConfiguration {
  
  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public HealthMvcEndpoint healthMvcEndpoint(HealthEndpoint delegate) {
      return new HealthMvcEndpoint(delegate, true);
  }
  
}
```

Could you help me to do the same in spring actuator v2.3.1 and spring v5.2.7, because there are many classes not available in the new version.
Thanks,

Comment: As mentioned in the initial Github ticket, I suggest to start with the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki#release-notes) of each version to see what changed and what you need to change. Also you might want to change 1 version at a time instead of skipping 4 version (2.0, 2.1, 2.2 and then 2.3). Makes it more consumable to migrate. Smaller steps.

Answer (score 3):

This configuration worked for me (for a SpringMVC project with spring boot actuator)

```
@Configuration
@Import({
        EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class,

        InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,

        WebEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        ServletManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class,
        ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class,
})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CorsEndpointProperties.class)
class ActuatorConfiguration {

    @Bean //taken from WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class
    public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties,
                                                                         WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties) {
        List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
        allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
        allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(webEndpointProperties.getBasePath());
        return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes,
                corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(),
                new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, webEndpointProperties.getBasePath()));
    }

    @Bean
    DispatcherServletPath dispatcherServletPath() {
        return () -> "/";
    }

}
```

I did include

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

for compatibility with the baseline Spring version I've been using (5.1.19.RELEASE)

The actuator endpoints are exposed with `/actuator/*`

Comment: thanks for your answer, my colleague managed to find the solution ;)

Comment: I can imagine, it has been quite a while. But as I haven't found and answer to the question and was struggling myself - maybe it'll help others. If the answer is inline with what you've built - I'd appreciate accepting the answer. It'll help others as well

Comment: @mazenaissa Do you mind sharing the solution, please? I too am dealing with this and cannot seem to enable additional endpoints besides `health` (which is enabled by default).

Comment: Could WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class be included in the imports instead of copy/pasting part of it's code? Also one class has been deprecated: For versions > 2.2.0 you should replace HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class with HealthContributorAutoConfiguration